# Passing array to component, devtools sees it, the component does not

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm passing an array to a component but the component sees the array as undefined. Here is the parent calling the component...

```
<FileList ref="files" class="ma-3 pa-0" :passFiles="true" :passedFiles="header.files"></FileList>
```

Vue devtools sees the array, it is valid. As seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Yet in my created hook in the controller, it shows this.passedFiles as undefined. (this.passFiles, however, shows correctly as true.)

```
created(){
       console.log(this.passFiles,this.passedFiles); //this.passedFiles shows as undefined
       window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
},
```

I dumped the array right before it gets sent to the component, and it is there, see screenshot:

[image]

I tried this just to make sure, and it gets passed to the array fine:

```
:passedFiles="[{0: '1'}]"
```

I'm pulling my hair out here. Here is the full component, it is long but it shows you everything

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="text-center pa-10" v-show="loading">
            <v-progress-circular
                :size="35"
                :width="3"
                color="primary"
                indeterminate
            ></v-progress-circular>
        </div>
        <v-data-table
            v-show="!loading"
            :headers="showActions ? headers : headersRead"
            :items="orderedFiles"
            :items-per-page="paginate"
            :footer-props="{'items-per-page-options':[paginate, 15, 30, 50, 100, -1]}"
            :hide-default-footer="oneFileOnly"
            class="elevation-1 custom-rounded-box ma-0 pa-0"
            ref="aWidth"
            :style="forceHeight&&$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'height:'+forceHeight+'px;' : ''"
        >
            <template slot="no-data">
                <div>There are currently no files here</div>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.description="{item, index}">
                <v-row
                    no-gutters
                    style="flex-wrap: nowrap;"
                >
                    <v-col
                        cols="12"
                        md="11"
                        class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                        <v-tooltip bottom v-if="item.description">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <a
                                    v-if="item.gdoc"
                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: orange;"
                                    v-bind="attrs"
                                    v-on="on"
                                    @click.prevent="gdocDialog = true;editingFile = item"
                                    class="d-block text-truncate"
                                    :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'max-width:'+aWidth+'px;' : 'max-width:'+bWidth+'px;'"
                                >
                                    {{item.description}}
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    v-else
                                    :href="'/getFile?id='+item.id"
                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: orange;"
                                    v-bind="attrs"
                                    v-on="on"
                                    class="d-block text-truncate"
                                    :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'max-width:'+aWidth+'px;' : 'max-width:'+bWidth+'px;'"
                                >
                                    {{item.description}}
                                </a>
                            </template>
                            <span>{{item.file_name_original}}</span>
                        </v-tooltip>
                        <div v-else>
                            <a
                                v-if="item.gdoc"
                                style="text-decoration: none; color: orange;"
                                @click.prevent="gdocDialog = true;editingFile = item"
                                class="d-block text-truncate"
                                :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'max-width:'+aWidth+'px;' : 'max-width:'+bWidth+'px;'"
                            >
                                {{item.file_name_original}}
                            </a>
                            <a
                                v-else
                                :href="'/getFile?id='+item.id"
                                style="text-decoration: none; color: orange;"
                                class="d-block text-truncate"
                                :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp ? 'max-width:'+aWidth+'px;' : 'max-width:'+bWidth+'px;'"
                            >
                                {{item.file_name_original}}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col
                        cols="12"
                        md="1"
                        style="min-width: 30px; max-width: 30px;"
                        class="flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0"
                        v-show="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp"
                    >
                        <v-edit-dialog
                            :return-value.sync="item.description"
                            @save="editFileInline()"
                            @open="inlineEditOpen(item, index)"
                            v-if="showActions"
                        >
                            <template v-slot:input>
                                <v-text-field
                                    ref="inline_file"
                                    v-model="editingFile.description"
                                    label="Edit"
                                    single-line
                                    counter
                                ></v-text-field>
                            </template>
                            <v-tooltip bottom>
                                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                    <v-icon
                                        small
                                        class="ml-2"
                                        color="orange"
                                        v-bind="attrs"
                                        v-on="on"
                                        width="100%"
                                    >
                                        mdi-pencil
                                    </v-icon>
                                </template>
                                <span>Edit the file description</span>
                            </v-tooltip>
                        </v-edit-dialog>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>

            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.icon="{ item }">
                <v-icon
                    :color="item.icon_color"
                >
                    {{item.icon}}
                </v-icon>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:item.uploaded="{ item }">
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <div v-bind="attrs"
                             v-on="on">
                            {{item.date_difference}}
                        </div>
                    </template>
                    <span>
                        <v-avatar
                            size="26px"
                            class="mr-2"
                        >
                            <img
                                :src="'/img/profile-pictures/'+item.user.profile_photo_thumb"
                            >
                        </v-avatar>
                        {{item.pretty_date}} by {{item.user.full_name}}</span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:item.actions="{item}" v-if="showActions">
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                        <v-icon
                            small
                            color="red"
                            @click="showDeleteDialog(item)"
                            v-bind="attrs"
                            v-on="on"
                        >
                            mdi-delete
                        </v-icon>
                    </template>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </v-tooltip>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>


        <!-- Upload modal -->
        <v-dialog
            v-model="fileUploadDialog"
            max-width="500px"
            width="500px"
            :transition="transitionSiteWide()"
            persistent
            v-if="showActions"
        >
            <v-card>
                <v-progress-linear
                    indeterminate
                    color="yellow darken-2"
                    v-show="fileUploadProcess"
                ></v-progress-linear>
                <v-toolbar
                    dark
                    class="primary"
                    dense
                    elevation="0"
                >
                    <v-icon class="mr-2">mdi-cloud-upload</v-icon>
                    <v-toolbar-title class="text">Upload File(s)</v-toolbar-title>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-toolbar>

                <v-card-text class="pt-3" v-show="!fileUploadGDoc">
                    <template>
                        <v-file-input
                            small-chips
                            :label="!oneFileOnly ? 'Upload multiple files by clicking here' : 'Click here to upload a file'"
                            type="file"
                            ref="files"
                            :accept="acceptedFiles()"
                            @change="onFilePicked()"
                            :key="componentKey"
                            show-size
                            counter
                            :multiple="!oneFileOnly"
                            :rules="!oneFileOnly ? rules : rulesSingle"
                        ></v-file-input>
                    </template>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-text class="pt-3" v-show="fileUploadGDoc">
                    <v-text-field
                        ref="gdoc_description"
                        v-model="gdoc_description"
                        label="Description"
                        :rules="gdoc_description_rules"
                        prepend-icon="mdi-pencil"
                    ></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field
                        ref="gdoc_link"
                        v-model="gdoc_link"
                        label="Link to your Google Document"
                        :rules="gdoc"
                        prepend-icon="mdi-google-drive"
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn
                        text
                        @click="ok"
                    >
                        Close
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                        class="primary"
                        text
                        v-show="fileUploadButton"
                        @click="uploadFiles()"
                        :loading="fileUploadProcess"
                    >
                        Upload
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                        class="primary"
                        text
                        v-show="gdocValidated()"
                        @click="uploadFiles()"
                        :loading="fileUploadProcess"
                    >
                        Attach
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>

        <!-- Delete dialog -->
        <v-dialog
            v-if="showActions"
            v-model="deleteFileConfirm"
            max-width="400px"
            :transition="transitionSiteWide()"
        >
            <v-card elevation="0">
                <v-progress-linear
                    indeterminate
                    color="yellow darken-2"
                    v-show="deleteFileLoading"
                ></v-progress-linear>
                <v-toolbar
                    dark
                    class="primary"
                    dense
                    elevation="0"
                >
                    <v-icon class="mr-2">mdi-text-box-minus</v-icon>
                    <v-toolbar-title class="text">{{editingFile.description ? editingFile.description : editingFile.file_name_original}}</v-toolbar-title>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-card-text class="pb-0">
                    <v-container>
                        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this file?</p>
                        <p>{{editingFile.description ? editingFile.description : editingFile.file_name_original}}
                            will be removed from the system.</p>
                    </v-container>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn
                        text
                        @click="deleteFileConfirm = false"
                    >
                        Close
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn
                        class="primary"
                        text
                        @click="deleteSet()"
                    >
                        Yes, delete this file
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>

        <!-- Gdoc dialog -->
        <v-dialog
            v-model="gdocDialog"
            max-width="1000px"
            width="100%"
            :transition="transitionSiteWide()"
        >
            <v-card elevation="0">
                <v-toolbar
                    dark
                    color="teal"
                    dense
                    elevation="0"
                >
                    <v-icon class="mr-2">mdi-google-drive</v-icon>
                    <v-toolbar-title class="text">{{editingFile.description ? editingFile.description : editingFile.file_name_original}}</v-toolbar-title>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-card-text class="pa-0">
                    <iframe ref="gdocIframe" :src="editingFile.file_name_original" :style="'height:'+iframeHeight+'px;width:100%;border:0'"></iframe>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                    <v-btn
                        text
                        @click="gdocDialog = false"
                    >
                        Close
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn
                        class="primary"
                        text
                        link
                        @click="openGdoc(editingFile.file_name_original);"
                    >
                        Open in new window
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            type: String,
            id: [Number, String],
            paginate: Number,
            fileUploadDialog: Boolean,
            fileUploadGDoc: Boolean,
            ok: Function,
            showActions: Boolean,
            forceHeight: { type: Number, default: 0 },
            oneFileOnly: Boolean,
            passFiles: Boolean,
            passedFiles: Array,
        },
        data () {
            return {
                headers: [
                    {
                        text: '',
                        align: 'start',
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'icon',
                        width: '20px'
                    },
                    { text: 'Description', value: 'description', sortable: false, },
                    { text: 'Uploaded', value: 'uploaded', width: '150px' },
                    { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false, width: '80px', align: 'center' },
                ],
                headersRead: [
                    {
                        text: '',
                        align: 'start',
                        sortable: false,
                        value: 'icon',
                        width: '20px'
                    },
                    { text: 'Description', value: 'description', sortable: false, },
                    { text: 'Uploaded', value: 'uploaded', width: '150px' },
                ],
                rules: [
                    files => !files || !files.some(file => file.size > 20_097_152) || 'Each file cannot exceed 20mb',
                ],
                rulesSingle: [

                ],
                gdoc: [
                    (value) => !!value || "Required",
                    (value) => this.isURL(value) || "URL is not valid",
                ],
                gdoc_description_rules: [
                    (value) => !!value || "Required",
                ],
                files: [],
                fileUploadButton: false,
                deleteFileConfirmLoading: false,
                fileUpload: false,
                fileUploadProcess: false,
                componentKey: 0,
                postFormData: new FormData(),
                editingFile: {
                    description: null,
                    index: null,
                    file_name_original: null,
                },

                deleteFileConfirm : false,
                deleteFileLoading: false,
                gdoc_link: null,
                gdoc_description: null,
                gdocDialog: false,
                iframeHeight: 0,
                aWidth: 0,
                loading: true,
            }
        },
        computed:{
            orderedFiles: function () {
                return _.orderBy(this.files, 'created_at', 'desc')
            },
        },
        watch: {
            files: {
                immediate: false,
                handler(){
                    if(this.files){
                        this.total = this.files.length;
                        this.$emit('totalFiles', this.total);
                    }else{
                        this.total = 0;
                    }

                },
            },
            id: {
                immediate: false,
                handler(){
                    this.getFiles()
                },
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async getFiles(){
                this.loading = true;
                await axios
                    .get('/app/files/getFiles?id=' + this.id + '&type=' + this.type)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.length) {
                            this.files = response.data;
                            this.$emit('totalFiles', this.files.length);
                            this.resize();
                            this.loading = false;
                        } else {
                            this.files = [];
                            this.$emit('totalFiles', 0);
                            this.loading = false;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        this.majorError();
                    })
                    .finally()
            },
            onFilePicked(e) {
                this.postFormData = new FormData();
                if(this.$refs.files.validate()){
                    this.fileUploadButton = true;
                }
                this.postFormData = new FormData();
                for(let key in event.target.files){
                    if(key >= 0){
                        this.postFormData.append( 'files[]', event.target.files[key]);
                    }
                }

            },
            async uploadFiles(){
                this.fileUploadProcess = true;
                this.postFormData.append('type', this.type);
                this.postFormData.append('id', this.id);
                this.postFormData.append('gdoc', this.fileUploadGDoc);
                this.postFormData.append('gdoc_link', this.gdoc_link);
                this.postFormData.append('gdoc_description', this.gdoc_description);
                const res = await this.callApi('post', '/app/files/uploadFiles', this.postFormData);
                if(res.status===200){
                    this.componentKey++; //reset trick
                    this.snackbar(res.data.msg,res.data.type);
                    this.ok();
                    this.fileUploadProcess = false;
                    this.gdoc_link = null;
                    this.gdoc_description = null;
                    this.$refs.gdoc_link.reset()
                    this.$refs.gdoc_description.reset()

                    if(res.data.files){
                        for (const file of res.data.files) {
                            this.files.push(file);
                        }
                    }
                    this.resize();
                    this.fileUploadButton = false;
                }else{
                    this.fileUploadProcess = false;
                    this.snackbar(res.data.msg, res.data.type);
                }

            },

            inlineEditOpen (item) {
                let obj = { ...item, editingIndex: this.files.indexOf(item) }
                this.editingFile = obj;
            },
            async editFileInline(){

                const file = Object.assign({}, this.editingFile); //Turn array into object for laravel
                const res = await this.callApi('post', '/app/files/updateFile',
                    {file: file});

                if(res.status===201){
                    this.files[this.editingFile.editingIndex].description = this.editingFile.description;
                    this.snackbar(this.editingFile.description + " has been edited successfully", 'success');
                    this.resize();
                }else{
                    if(res.status===422){
                        for(let i in res.data.errors) {
                            this.snackbar(res.data.errors[i][0], 'error');
                        }
                    }else{
                        this.snackbar("There has been an error, we don't have any more information for you", 'error');
                    }
                }
            },

            showDeleteDialog(file){
                this.deleteFileConfirm = true;
                let obj = { ...file, index: this.files.indexOf(file)}
                this.editingFile= obj;
            },
            async deleteSet(){
                this.deleteFileLoading = true;
                const res = await this.callApi('post', '/app/files/deleteFile', this.editingFile);

                if(res.status===200){
                    this.files.splice(this.editingFile.index, 1);
                    this.snackbar("File deleted successfully", 'success');
                    this.deleteFileConfirm = false;
                }else{
                    if(res.status===422){
                        this.snackbar(res.data.msg, 'error');
                    }
                }
                this.deleteFileLoading = false;
            },

            gdocValidated(){
                if(this.gdoc_link&&this.$refs.gdoc_link.validate()&&this.gdoc_description){
                    return true;
                }
            },
            openGdoc(url){
                window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
            },

            onResize() {
                this.iframeHeight =  window.innerHeight - 220;
                if(this.showActions){
                    this.aWidth = this.$refs.aWidth.$el.clientWidth - 355;
                    this.bWidth = this.$refs.aWidth.$el.clientWidth - 150;
                }else{
                    this.aWidth = this.$refs.aWidth.$el.clientWidth - 270;
                    this.bWidth = this.$refs.aWidth.$el.clientWidth - 65;
                }
            },
            resize(){
                setTimeout(() =>  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')), 1);
            },
        },
        async mounted(){
            if(this.passFiles){
                this.files = this.passedFiles;
                //console.log(this.passedFiles,this.files)
                this.loading = false;
            }else{
                this.getFiles();
            }
            this.onResize();
            this.resize();
        },
        created(){
            console.log(this.passFiles,this.passedFiles); //this.passedFiles shows as undefined
            window.addEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
        },
        destroyed(){
            window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onResize);
            this.editingFile = null;
        },
    }
</script>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `header.files` is probably set by async call so 1st it is undefined, this value is used to init internal component data (`this.files` in `mounted`), later when `header.files` is fully loaded, the change is not reflected inside the component

Comment: @MichalLevý - You were right, I had to do some initial checks to make sure the data was loaded before rendering the FileList. Thank you!

Comment: It clearly shows that data is not available. Hence, please check if data is available in mounted() hook. As created() has been called before mounted() and sometimes data not returning back till that execution.